# Image or file corrupted when success upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropbox, dropzone.js

Hi im trying to upload file or image in my dropbox using dropzone. and when it successfully upload in my dropbox it just corrupted it cant be preview.. I was wondering if there's a problem with my codes in getting a file

This is my processing method inside of my `init: function()`

```
    this.on("processing", function(file) {

         var url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload';
         var file = dropzone.files[0];  
         var filename = file.name;


         $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: 'post',
           processData: false,
           contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
           headers: {
           "Authorization": "ACCESS TOKEN",
           "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path": "/'+filename+'","mode": "add"}'
           },

           success: function (data){
          alert('Success Upload');
            /*this.options.url = url;*/
            console.log(data);
           }

          })

  });
```

Comment: You don't seem to be supplying the file data anywhere in the upload call. Here's an example of uploading to the Dropbox API in JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dropbox-api/409/uploading-a-file/1359/uploading-a-file-via-jquery-in-javascript#t=201701260350392030997

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm may be you are not uploading the file with the proper headers. If you can please use curl first instead of using javascript so you can check faster if your file is being uploaded or not.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload

I don't know if you have already checked the API documentation, first test it using curl and then form the packet using javascript.

> curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
>       --header "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN
>
> " \
>       --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/Homework/math/Matrices.txt\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\":
>   true,\"mute\": false}" \
>       --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
>       --data-binary @local_file.txt

I hope this can help you...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your internet connection? I ask because I had a similar problem, and even though my network was "fast", turns out my network is a burst type of network and the image was only uploading 2 of the 5 mb file size before the burst traffic timed out.

Crazy I know, but if you think that not might be the issue. Have you debugged this script yet? Are you getting your alert on screen and in your console debugger?

Comment: Well my internet connection is fine. I console it and it just returned a successful upload with the details of a the image/file

Comment: Is the file uploading anything? Or is the file size 0? This will help debug a little.

Comment: It upload in my dropbox and the file size is 0